# Post formats and template hierarchy

Tags: post-formats

I want to use post formats but the theme (WP-Bootstrap by 320Press) on which my current template is based doesn't make use of the content.php template, only single.php.

Is it possible to edit the template hierarchy so that you can append formats to the single template (single-image.php, for example)? Alternatively, if this is best avoided, can anyone suggest another workaround?

Comment: Take a look here - [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). It will hopefully give you an insight in to how WP determains which template to use. Any way, while questions relating to themes are technically off-topic here, usually people will try to help if they can. The problem is though, you've not posted the code for **single.php**, so it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to make this work if your theme don't support [post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)

- Create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- [`add_theme_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Formats) for post formats
- Remove the loop from your template files and add replace it with `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );`. Your template should look like this

  ```
  if ( have_posts() ) { // <- Not necessary in single.php

      while ( have_posts() ) {
          the_post();

          get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

      }

  }
  ```
- Everything else should go into a new file which should be called `content.php`
- Create a new file called `content-image.php` and add the loop in there and modify as needed
- When a post is assigned the `image` post format, `content-image.php` will be used inside single.php to display the image posts

Look at one of the bundled themes how to exactly make use of post formats